# What TNG episode is this clip of Jean-Luc Picard wearing a suit from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification, jean-luc-picard

I've been enjoying the recent Honest Trailer regarding *Star Trek: The Next Generation*. However, I cannot place what episode [this clip](https://youtu.be/-6Zc8Co2H3w?t=3m19s) below is from - I don't recall Picard ever donning such an outfit, and my googling has been unsuccessful. I was curious if this might be an outtake rather than from a particular episode.

[image: Picard in a suit]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's from the end of [TNG: The Big Goodbye.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Big_Goodbye_(episode)) Picard is dressed as Dixon Hill and delivers a speech to the Jarada.

Comment: You utter ****. I was a second away from clicking submit.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I shy away from rewatching the first season of TNG, so I had forgotten about this.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Completely spaced on that.